# JQuery Username Validation with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using the best tutorial of encosia website which was written by David ward and by his example given in his website for instant validation of username.

Here is the link of the original post:
http://encosia.com/aspnet-username-availability-checking-via-ajax/

So the problem here with this code is though I am using my custom membership it is always showing me the user is "`Available`" instead of "`Not Available`" if the user is not in the database.

Here is my code:

```
      protected void Username_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    if (Membership.GetUser(Username.Text) != null)
    {
      UserAvailability.InnerText = "Username taken, sorry.";
      UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "taken");
      Button1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
      UserAvailability.InnerText = "Username available!";
      UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "available");
      Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
  }
```

This is my web.config:

```
     <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CustomMembership;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

 <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembership">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomMembership"
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
            requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            passwordAttemptWindow="5"
            passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why you do System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);?

Comment: When the user enters the name and hits the tab button then just I need o update the progress so I used it.

Comment: Did you create user database using aspnet_regsql?

Comment: Try debugging Username.Text, or set someLabel.Text = Username.Text to check if it is properly passed to method.

Comment: Yes I did the debugging actually it's jumpinng over to jquery 1.3 file  so I couldn't trace out the username.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing (Username.Text) with (sender as TextBox).Text, if protected void Username_Changed is triggered by change in textbox